# Windows 7 Home Premium - Networking/Internet/Services Problems?

Tags: windows-7, networking, services, wired-networking

Okay I made a horrible mistake, I take full blame. I was wanting to improve performance, and modified my services according to the Black Viper Win7 Services Guide.

http://www.blackviper.com/service-configurations/black-vipers-windows-7-service-pack-1-service-configurations/

Problem 1. Now network/internet does not work at all. This is not a hardware issue, as I am dual-booted Win7/Debian8. And booted to Debian, internet works fine, as in aka I am on it atm.

Problem 2. Trying to access any services or control panel menu is incredibly slow, never had problems like this before. When I try to do anything, it basically waits a long while, then it just times out.

Problem 3. Because of Problem #2, none of the built in troubleshooters work at all. Can not get to them, and therefore have the OS tools fix my network/internet issues.

So my attempts to fix this have been several.

I have tried different freeware to help fix  my network/internet, but after many attempts, and no results, it is clearly an issue of a services misconfiguration.

I don't have a recent backup, and doing reformat is clearly out of order, because of my dual boot. I wish to keep this, just fix it somehow.

I just downloaded some registry fixes, that restore services back to default settings.

However, that even timed out, when trying to merge.

So I have to fix problem #2, so that I can use built in tools.

I am completely unable using the Services Menu to able to start anything, I can stop and change automatic/manual/disable, but starting is hard to do. or takes a long time.

What can you suggest, to fix this?

Is there a better tool?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: System restore?

Comment: Had that disabled. I do take backups, but not regular enough. So there has to be a way to fix this.

Comment: I can't believe you'd take advice from a guy that looks like that, or one that calls himself "Black Viper."

Comment: That guy has been around a long time. Instead of just looking for something negative to say, just give me any suggestions that help me. If not, just go do something else.

Comment: does starting in safe mode with or without networking let you get to the control panel?